# how to use several mapsforge map files?

Tags: osmdroid, mapsforge

I try to use OSMdroid with offline maps but I wonder how to use several map files as mapsforge provides several files to cover French country.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
boolean setMapsForgeTileProvider(){

    GenericMapView genericMap = (GenericMapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/mapsforge/";
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    if (listOfFiles == null)
        return false;

    File mapFile = null;
    for (File file:listOfFiles){
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".map")){
            mapFile = file;
            MapsForgeTileProvider mfProvider = new MapsForgeTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(getActivity()), mapFile);
            final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(mfProvider, getActivity());
            tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            genericMap.setTileProvider(mfProvider);
            mMapView = genericMap.getMapView();
            mMapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
        }
    }

    if (mapFile == null)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

In fact maps are here, I can see it briefly when I zoom in and out but they are displayed on a white background instead of transparent and so they are masked.

Anyway, is it the right way to do it?

Thanks,